# User Import with inactive status

Tags: users, importing-exporting

I have a site where we need to bulk import users into the system, however the client wants to be able to import the users into the system but have them inactive until a later date,

The idea is that we operate online training courses, so we will receive user data from an organisation as part of our onboarding - however we do not want to give the users access to the system until it is time for them to start their course.

My idea was to use the User Import module to bulk import - however I can not see a way to set the 'status' of users when importing - as a result all users have instant access to the system. Is there any way to do this with the User Import module?

If it was possible, we would then use a VBO operation to change the status of the users to active at the appropriate date - this would also mean that users would receive the site configured activation email with the appropriate log-in information,

Any help or alternative implementation suggestions would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks,

Comment: Have you looked into using the Feeds Import module to create a user importer?

Comment: As for the bulk operations, this ticket suggests that the "Unblock Users" operation should automatically send the activation email: https://www.drupal.org/node/667702 -- You may want to try importing the users with a special hidden field containing a certain value so you can filter by that value when performing the bulk operation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. No I haven't tried the Feeds module - I came across the User Import as it seemed the obvious solution based on it's name. Will investigate Feeds and see what it offers.
Yeah I've successfully tested the sending of activation emails on unblocking users, so it's now just a case of getting a solution which imports users as blocked by default rather than active.

Answer (score 0):

The **Feeds module** - https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds - provided me with the solution to this issue.

Feeds allow you set both the Status of the whole import, and a per user status by adding a Status column to your CSV,

For users who have the same problem, this how you do either:

---

#### 1. General Status for User Import

Once you have installed the Feeds module go Structure/Feeds Importer/User Import - admin/structure/feeds/user - and go to the **Settings** option in the **Processor** section, here you will find an option to set the Status of all imported users:

[image: Feeds User Importer Status Settings]

---

#### 2. Status column in Import CSV

If you want to add a status column to your CSV file, allowing some users records to be imported as active and others as blocked, then you need to edit the **Mapping** in the Processor section - again at admin/structure/feeds/user. Add a new field to the mapping selecting 'Account Status' as the target field.

Inside your CSV **use the values 0 or 1 for the status** - where 0 is 'blocked' and 1 is 'active'.

Note: this will override any default status defined by the steps outline in Option 1 above.

---

---

I can also confirm that VBO operation to unblock users will also result in the correct Activation emails being sent out to the users (provided you have an activation email configured in Account settings)

Comment: Today nov22, no option available to set status (blocked or active) for imported users. Default will import as blocked.